# Sublime Text 2 and Repl - Run python

Tags: python, path, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I am start using Sublime Text 2 and REPL and got some problems.
When I run the file it tells me that the file du not exist. The script works perfect if it is build directly from the terminal.

**Code**

```
def stopwords(text):
    with open('danish', 'rU') as f:
        for line in f:
            text = text.replace(' '+line.strip()+' ', "")
    return text
```

**Log**

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'danish'
```

i have tried things like `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))) reload(sys)` and `__file__` but they do not work.

Any ideas why `__file__` don't work when running through Sublime Text 2 REPL or what where the file are stored??